# Is there a memory size limit to download from draw.io an image in some formats?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I drew a figure to download by appending many different images from my computer. Now I try to download as .png file but it does not give any response after it opens a new tab. I tried it on both Chrome and Firefox but the result is the same. I only can download it as .xml file.

So I thought that may be a size limit to convert the figure to any image type.

Is it true - is there any such limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome, Edge and Firefox export images locally on the client, so the limit there is the CPU and availabile memory on your machine.

For IE 11 and Safari the image export is via a server, so bandwidth is an additional factor there. If you're using one of these, try again with a browser in the first set.